# Parameter 'updateBy' not found. Available parameters are [0, createBy, param1, param2]

Tags: mybatis

I'd like to execute a "SELECT" command with only one parameter: createBy (actually I don't know how does the dao.xml manage the first generics parameter, so in my opinion, there is only one parameter), why does Mybatis throw the exception: parameter 'updateBy' not found? with the if condition: `<if test="updateBy != null and updateBy.id != null and updateBy.id != ''">`
The dao.java is:

`public List<T> findList(T entity, @Param("createBy") User createBy);`

And the select sql in dao.xml is:

```
<select id="findList" resultType="ChenminIndicator">
    SELECT 
        <include refid="chenminIndicatorColumns"/>
    FROM chenmin_indicator a
    <include refid="chenminIndicatorJoins"/>
    <where>
        a.del_flag = #{DEL_FLAG_NORMAL}
        <if test="createBy != null and createBy.id != null and createBy.id != ''">
            AND a.create_by = #{createBy.id}
        </if>
        <if test="updateBy != null and updateBy.id != null and updateBy.id != ''">
            AND a.update_by = #{updateBy.id}
        </if>

    </where>
    <choose>
        <when test="page !=null and page.orderBy != null and page.orderBy != ''">
            ORDER BY ${page.orderBy}
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            ORDER BY a.update_date DESC
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what result you expect. To evaluate the if condition, there needs to be a parameter or variable named `updateBy`.

Comment: I want to select the information of the specified creator (specified by parameter createBy), I don't input any other parameters, so I'm confused why the parameter 'updateBy' is needed.

Comment: As I explained, MyBatis needs `updateBy` parameter to evaluate the `if` condition. If you don't need the `AND a.update_by = ...` part, you should remove the `<if />`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I think that's the key, but it is expected that: if I only pass the parameter 'createBy', MySQL executes 'select XXX from XXX where createBy=XXX'; and if I pass the parameter 'createBy' and 'updateBy', MySQL executes 'select XXX from XXX where createBy=XXX and updateBy=XXX.

Comment: How do you plan to pass `updateBy`? It should work, of course, if you change the method signature to `public List<T> findList(T entity, @Param("createBy") User createBy, @Param("updateBy") User updateBy)`. If you don't need `update_by` = XXX` condition, pass `null` as `updateBy`. Is this what you want?

Comment: This should work, of course, but actually, there are many other fields of the table (e.g. name, source, country, e.t.c, which were omitted when I threw this question for simplicity), which are all listed in the searching page for searching, and the user may search with zero or one or more fields (parameters), so maybe changing the method signature is not scalable.

Comment: Your question was 'why does Mybatis throw the exception: parameter 'updateBy' not found?' and you've got the answer, I guess. If you want to know how to handle many dynamic criteria, you should rephrase the question or ask a new question. Either way, you should provide more details.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is right to this question, maybe I failed to describe my question clearly, I post a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64272763/how-to-select-data-of-the-specified-createby, could you please review it?