# How to select data of the specified 'createBy'

Tags: mybatis

I want to execute the SELECT command to find the data of the specified 'createBy', and the dao.xml is as follows (some fields are omitted for simplicity):

```
<select id="findList" resultType="ChenminIndicator">
    SELECT 
        <include refid="chenminIndicatorColumns"/>
    FROM chenmin_indicator a
    <include refid="chenminIndicatorJoins"/>
    <where>
        a.del_flag = #{DEL_FLAG_NORMAL}
        <if test="createBy != null and createBy.id != null and createBy.id != ''">
            AND a.create_by = #{createBy.id}
        </if>
        <if test="updateBy != null and updateBy.id != null and updateBy.id != ''">
            AND a.update_by = #{updateBy.id}
        </if>
        <if test="icode != null and icode != ''">
            AND a.icode = #{icode}
        </if>
    </where>
    <choose>
        <when test="page !=null and page.orderBy != null and page.orderBy != ''">
            ORDER BY ${page.orderBy}
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            ORDER BY a.update_date DESC
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</select>
```

I write the dao.java like this:

```
public List<T> findList(T entity, @Param("createBy") User createBy);
```

but Mybatis throws exception:

```
Parameter 'updateBy' not found. Available parameters are [0, createBy, param1, param2]
```

and if I write dao.java like:

```
public List<T> findList(T entity);
```

it works and return the total data, how can I select the data of one specified 'createBy'?

Comment: Is `entity` used in your `mybatis` block?

Comment: This question has bothered me for a few days, actually, I couldn't find how 'entity' is used in 'dao.xml', and I guess it's used to specify what table the user wants to search since there are many tables, whose service.java all extends the same one, which takes generics as a parameter.

Comment: I think you are supposed to use the `entity` parameter to pass the search criteria. e.g. `entity = new SomeEntity(); entity.setCreteBy(...); List<SomeEntity> list = findList(entity);` You should ask someone who created the mapper for a help, probably.